# What prep work can I do before transitioning from SEL to SES?

Tags: usa, seaplane

I'm very interested in getting my SES rating.  Is there any personal studying or prep work that I can do to minimize time in the air and with an instructor?

EDIT: I do have my SEL pilot license already.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/seaplane_handbook/)?

Answer (score 4):

If you already have a pilot license for single-engine land airplanes you've done a huge amount of prep work already - you know all the airspace, navigation, airwork, etc. that you need to know for your seaplane rating.
Brush up on all of that in the seaplane as you *can* be tested on it and the aerodynamics will be a bit different with floats hanging out there, but you're already well ahead of the game.
You need to learn how to take off, land, and taxi/sail all over again on water (which is arguably the hard part) but the bulk of your existing knowledge will transfer over.

For studying and prep I imagine [the FAA Seaplane Operations Handbook (FAA-H-8083-23)](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/seaplane_handbook/) would be the best place to look - it's pretty comprehensive.
Also if you can commandeer a seaplane pilot for some hangar flying (or better a pilot and aircraft for a few real-world touch-and-gos & some practice sailing the plane on water) that would obviously be a great advantage, but coming to your first lesson familiar with the Seaplane Operations Handbook would probably put you well ahead of the curve anyway.

Comment: I've familiarized myself a bit with that book already, but I'll make sure that I know it really well before I start my first lesson.  Also, I like the sound of "commandeering" an airplane hahaha.